# flickr project weather photo download

Tags: weather, flickr

I want to download the photos from flickr project weather. I looked at the documents for the flickr api, but I can't figure out how to get photos from a specific project. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

There may be a more direct solution with the API, but I would look at the `Python` package `mechanize` to download the html for the page and `BeautifulSoup` to parse the page's html and identify the links to the photos.